# Java - Convert an input string to Uppercase first letter and Lowercase other letters

Tags: java, string, char, uppercase, lowercase

I know there has been a similar question before but it doesn't actually solve my problem. I only want to get my string input which represents an employee name and make sure the input is this form "Name". Not "name", not "Name". So i tried to do it but the output doesn't work. So here is the code :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String ename; // input string
System.out.println("Enter Employee Name : (Type -Name-, not -name-, not -NAME-!!!");
ename = scanner.nextLine(); // read the string input
char[] Transform = new char[ename.length()]; // this array will contain the string split in characters
for (int i = 0;i < ename.length(); i++)
{
    Transform[i] = ename.charAt(i);  // Split the input to a char array
}
Transform[0] = Character.toUpperCase(Transform[0]); // First Letter Always Capital
for (int i = 1;i < ename.length(); i++)
{
    Transform[i] = Character.toLowerCase(Transform[0]); // Other letters small
}
String name = new String(Transform); // convert the array to a new String variable
System.out.println("NEW STRING : " + name );
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: This line `Transform[i] = Character.toLowerCase(Transform[0]);` should be `Transform[i] = Character.toLowerCase(Transform[i]);`. Closing for simple typo.

Comment: I have been programming for 3 hours straight and it was right in front of my eyes and I just couldn't see it!

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. `PascalCase` is reserved for classes, variables are **always** in `camelCase`. Not doing so is not only confusing for other developers, but also plays havoc with the syntax highlighting here on SO.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I did not understand what you meant by PascalCase and camelcase

Comment: Look at the way I wrote them. It's not rocket science. Also, there's this thing called Google. Apparently it's good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Statement in the i loop to

```
 Transform[i] = Character.toLowerCase(Transform[i]);
```

adding `Transform[i]` and not `Transform[0]` because you are inserting same first character again and again to the array

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/9G1vVm)

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know why you need all this code.**

For example:

```
char[] transform = new char[ename.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < ename.length(); i++) {
    transform[i] = ename.charAt(i);
}
```

is *identical* to

```
char[] transform = ename.toCharArray();
```

And your entire code can be rewritten as:

```
public static String capitalise(final String name) {
    return name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + name.substring(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(capitalise("Name"));
    System.out.println(capitalise("name"));
    System.out.println(capitalise("NamE"));
    System.out.println(capitalise("NAMe"));
}
```

Output:

```
Name
Name
Name
Naae
```